# Move all pods to same node after scaling down in AKS

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

We have a deployment in AKS that we scale down in the evening to 3 and up to 9 in the morning.

There are resources on a node for 3 of those pods only. So in the morning 2 new nodes should be created by AKS.

But what happens is that the the scale down in the evening sometimes kills 2 pods on every node to keep 3 running nodes with 1 pod on them. Sometimes 2 nodes, 1 with 1 pod and 1 with 2 pods.

What we want is to run 1 node with 3 pods at night.

How can we accomplish this?

Comment: I believe you can achieve that using additional node pool with one node and additional deployment with node selector specified for that node pool. in the evening you scale up additional deployment and scale down main deployment and it's node pool to zero. The next morning you do the opposite.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked [Cluster Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler)? In theory this can help achieve what you asking for?

> Cluster Autoscaler is a standalone program that adjusts the size of a
> Kubernetes cluster to meet the current needs.
>
> Cluster Autoscaler is a tool that automatically adjusts the size of
> the Kubernetes cluster when one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - there are pods that failed to run in the cluster due to insufficient resources.
> - there are nodes in the cluster that have been underutilized for an extended period of time and their pods can be placed on other existing
>   nodes.

---

Why exactly this autoscaler or [How is Cluster Autoscaler different from CPU-usage-based node autoscalers](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-is-cluster-autoscaler-different-from-cpu-usage-based-node-autoscalers) ?

> Cluster Autoscaler makes sure that all pods in the cluster have a
> place to run, no matter if there is any CPU load or not. **Moreover, it
> tries to ensure that there are no unneeded nodes in the cluster.**
>
> CPU-usage-based (or any metric-based) cluster/node group autoscalers
> don't care about pods when scaling up and down. As a result, they may
> add a node that will not have any pods, or remove a node that has some
> system-critical pods on it, like kube-dns. Usage of these autoscalers
> with Kubernetes is discouraged.

Check [cluster-autoscaler aks addon example](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/tree/master/examples/addons/cluster-autoscaler)